# Query regarding generic sObject and specific sObject

Tags: apex, sobject

I was going through the 'Apex and Database basics' module in Trailhead and came across the following sentence in one of the units:

This example shows how the generic sObject variable can be assigned to any Salesforce object: an account and a custom object called Book__c.

```
sObject sobj1 = new Account(Name='Trailhead');
sObject sobj2 = new Book__c(Name='Workbook 1');
```

I think the sentence should have been like this: This example shows how the generic sObject variable can be assigned any Salesforce object: an account and a custom object called Book__c.
What I mean is isnt the specific object being assigned to the generic object and not the other way around? I hope I've clarified my concern.

Comment: It's somewhat regional and opinion based, but what they are saying is not wrong. It could be written more clearly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The specific type is indeed being assigned to the generic type. The way the trailhead module words it is indeed backwards (i.e. it describes `Account acct = genericSObject;`)

The action of going from a more specific type to a more general one is called *up-casting*. It's (almost) always possible to perform an up-cast (there are a few specific scenarios where it isn't possible, but those are the exception rather than the rule).

It is, however, also possible to *down-cast* in certain scenarios. As an example, try running the following code in an anonymous apex window:

```
Account myAccount = new Account(Name = 'my new account');
SObject genericSObj = myAccount;
Account otherAccountVariable = (Account)genericSObj;
```

Even though we stored the `Account` as a more general `SObject` type, Salesforce is able to remember enough about the original object in this scenario that we can down-cast back to an Account.

The `(Account)` part of `(Account)genericSObj;` is an example of explicitly type-casting an expression (whereas `genericSObj = myAccount;` is implicitly doing a type-cast). We need to explicitly type-cast when trying to down-cast.

Comment: Thanks.This clarification has helped me more. I'm preparing for the salesforce platform app builder certification. I wanted to know if the trailhead modules and the trailmix(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/00550000006yDdKAAU/trailmixes/prepare-for-your-salesforce-platform-app-builder-credential) be enough for the certification test. Could you give any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way you are reading it, I think in English that's a correct way of saying: "You can assign an Account type to the generic sObject type". You're understanding is correct.